# Using output of file as new variable for bash script

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to ping 2 different interfaces using the IPs generated by the following file.txt:

```
Eth1/1   ALL  ETHERNET   40   192.168.40.145  Device1-1  Eth16/1   192.168.40.144
Eth1/2   ALL  ETHERNET   40   192.168.41.145  Device1-2  Eth16/1   192.168.41.144
```

What I'm looking for is a script that allows me to first ssh into *Device1-1* and ping **192.168.40.145** from source **192.168.40.144** then ssh into *Device1-2* using a syntax like this:

```
ssh -q Device1-1 "ping 192.168.40.145 source 192.168.40.144" 
ssh -q Device1-2 "ping 192.168.41.145 source 192.168.41.144"
```

Is there any way I can open each ssh session in a different tab?

I'm having hard time to use different string characters from a text file as variables in a new script. There has to be a easy way to do this. Any suggestions?

Much appreciated!!!

Comment: What do you mean by `different tab`?

Comment: I use iTerm and the idea is that when I launch the script, I'd want the ssh sessions to be opened in two different tabs, other than the once that I'm currently running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably save the output in a new file `source` that.

```
awk '{print "ssh -q", "ping", $6, $5, "source", $NF}' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

The content of the `newfile.txt`

```
ssh -q ping Device1-1 192.168.40.145 source 192.168.40.144
ssh -q ping Device1-2 192.168.41.145 source 192.168.41.144
```

Source it.

```
source ./newfile.txt
```

Or maybe pipe the output to `bash`

```
awk '{print "ssh -q", "ping", $6, $5, "source", $NF}' file.txt | bash
```

Comment: Thx @jetchisel I'll try your suggestion and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You there is an easy way to do what you just described. If you use the `-t` flag in SSH you will execute the command right after logging in. Hope this helps. If not leave a comment so I can help some more. :)

- `ssh -t Device1-1 'ping 192.168.40.145 source 192.168.40.144'`

Comment: Thanks! It helps a bit, however I need to know how to extract those IPs from the text file. The above is just a tiny example, in reality I'd have few dozen rows. In other words, how can I define those particular IP's extracted from the file as variables used in my new script?